# Can I add application Insights to a C# class library?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I want to use Telemetric client operations for methods in a class library.
Mention the steps required for that.

Answer (score 4):

You definitely can.

Add latest AI Core SDK: Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights -Pre

Create AI resource it Azure portal.

Take its instrumentation key and put it in ApplicationInsights.config

Use TelemetryClient in your code to instrument your application:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/

Comment: When I added the AI package and used telemetric methods inside the library. The library is being called from  an MVC website. The following exception being occured. Can you help.


An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in SOP.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=0.13.2.132, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Do you reference ApplicationInsights from that MVC app? If you installed AI as I said you would reference .14. Can you update MVC app to use same version of application insights?

Comment: Does even make sense to add on a class library or makes more sense to add on higher level on web project for example?